# Issues with Loading and Vectorizing Multiple PDFs using Langchain

Tags: python, vectorization, embedding, langchain, large-language-model

I am trying to use `VectorstoreIndexCreator().from_loaders(loaders)` from the `langchain` package, where `loaders` is a list of `UnstructuredPDFLoader` instances, each intended to load a different PDF file. However, I am encountering an `UnboundLocalError` related to a local variable `isalnum`.

Here’s the relevant part of the error traceback:

```
File …/site-packages/unstructured/documents/elements.py:1007, in process_metadata….
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'isalnum' referenced before assignment
```

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```py
from langchain.document_loaders import UnstructuredPDFLoader
from langchain.indexes import VectorstoreIndexCreator

loaders = [UnstructuredPDFLoader(filepath) for filepath in filepaths]
index = VectorstoreIndexCreator().from_loaders(loaders)
```

Interestingly, when I use `WebBaseLoader` to load a web document instead of a PDF, the code works perfectly:

```py
from langchain.document_loaders import WebBaseLoader
from langchain.indexes import VectorstoreIndexCreator

loader = WebBaseLoader("https://example.com")
index = VectorstoreIndexCreator().from_loaders([loader])
```

#### Questions:

1. Has anyone encountered a similar issue with `UnstructuredPDFLoader` from `langchain`, and if so, how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved and the "VectorstoreIndexCreator" is now working again.

Answer (score 2):

There was an issue opened on the [unstructured io github repo](https://github.com/Unstructured-IO/unstructured) yesterday mentioning this same problem, so I suspect it's not something you're doing wrong but rather a temporary bug in the unstructured lib ([issue is here](https://github.com/Unstructured-IO/unstructured/issues/1584))